# array from input and unset

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i am having a problem, i cannot unset a session can anyone spot the error? the idea is to go through the process until array 4 where a session has been unset then return to array 3 and the session that was removed in array4 should be gone....but its not gone, i hope this makes sense, thank you all for any help.

HTML

```
    <form action="array2.php" method="post"> 
    <select name="tickets">
    Select amount of tickets you require.
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    Select the acomidation you require.
    <select name="accom">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="camping">Camping</option>
        <option value="caravan">Caravan</option>
    </select>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

array2

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_POST['tickets'] == "" || $_POST['accom'] == ""){
        header("Location: error.html");
        exit; 
    }else{
        $tickets = $_POST['tickets'];
        $accom = $_POST['accom'];
        $_SESSION['tickets'] = $tickets;
        $_SESSION['accom'] = $accom;
        header('Location: array3.php');
    }
}
```

?>

array3

```
<?php
session_start();
$tickets = $_SESSION['tickets'];
$accom = $_SESSION['accom'];
?>

    <form method="post" action="array4.php">
    <input type="submit" value="remove" />
</form>
<?php
    for($i=0; $i < count($tickets); $i++){
        echo "You have selected to recive " . $tickets[$i] . " tickets<br/>";
    }
    for($i=0; $i < count($accom); $i++){
        echo "And you have selected to recive " . $accom[$i] . " for accommodation are you sure? <br/>";
    }
?>
```

array4

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
    unset($_SESSION['accom']);
}
$tickets = $_SESSION['tickets'];
?>

<form method="post" action="array3.php">
    <input type="submit" value="go back?" />
</form>
<?php
    for($i=0; $i < count($tickets); $i++){
        echo "You have selected to recive " . $tickets[$i] . " tickets<br/>";
    }
    for($i=0; $i < count($accom); $i++){
        echo "And you have selected to recive " . $accom[$i] . " for accommodation are you sure? <br/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're unsetting `$_SESSION['accom']`, but you're using `$accom`, which was never updated...

Comment: He's setting that session variable in the second page.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
value="remove"
```

in (or just add this)

```
name="remove"
```

And don't use a for, for get an array, use a simple foreach

```
foreach($tickets as $ticket){
    echo "You have selected to recive $ticket tickets<br/>";
}
```

Comment: hello thank you or the reply, i am still having my problem of the session still existing after it's been unset if i go back to the previous page, is there anyone to fix this without? the idea is a shopping cart, you remove something then go back to it, and it has the item removed but the way it is at the moment, it still exists when you go back.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
    unset($_SESSION['accom']);
}
```

You would need this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'remove'){
    unset($_SESSION['accom']);
}
```

`$_POST` variables take the name of the form variable, not the value, as the key.

Comment: hello thank you or the reply, i have implemented your code however i am still having my problem of the session still existing after it's been unset if i go back to the previous page, is there anyone to fix this without? the idea is a shopping cart, you remove something then go back to it, and it has the item removed but the way it is at the moment, it still exists when you go back.

Comment: How are you getting back to the previous page? Do you mean with the back button?

Comment: i am using

<form method="post" action="array3.php">
    <input type="submit" value="go back?" />
</form>

just a button to take you to the prev page

Comment: Have you run through the entire process you outlined in your question after making these changes? Does page 4 still show the accom data? And where are you setting the `$accom` variables data on page 4?

Comment: yeh i did, and it doesnt show on array 4, but when i press the button to go back to array3.php it shows it still exists when it should be done since i unset it :/

Comment: If you've done that, and the button on page 3 is still coded as `<input type="submit" value="remove" />` - I really can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: yeh i hate it when something like this happens i bet its something tiny thats causign it swell here is what is currently happening
Fill out from
gets processed in array2.php & redirects to array3.php
in array3.php i click a button to remove one of the sessions, that takes me to array4.php
in array4.php it usets the session, now i have a button to take me back to array3.php
in array3.php the session i unset in array4.php is now back